# ¿Como hacer un campo autoincrementable en oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g

La tabla es la siguiente.

```
create table ventas(
    id_venta number(5) primary key,
    id_articulo number(5) references articulos,
    id_empleado number(6) references empleado, 
    id_cliente  number(5) references cliente, 
    cantidad number(10) not null,
    precio number(8) not null,
    total number(8) not null,
    fecha_venta date
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para resolver esto basta nomas con un trigger y haciendo uso de una secuencia como lo que se presenta acontinuacion.

```
create sequence Auidventa
start with 1
increment by 1  -- aqui lo hago es que determino apartir de que nuevo voy
                -- a iniciar y cuando va incrementar
order;

-- Creacion de trigger
create or replace trigger autoidventa
before insert on ventas
for each row
begin
  select Auidventa.nextval into :new.id_venta from dual;
end;
/
```

Ahora solo que da realizar la insercion comun en la tabla ventajas pero ojo **no especifique el campo id_venta, es decir no inserte ahi ya que ese el campo autoincrementable.**

Comment: Gracias por compartir. Una nota en cuanto a tu advertencia: aunque se intentara especificar `id_venta` en el `insert`, de todas maneras el trigger va a reemplazar el valor con el del sequence.

Comment: Denada, y gracias por las observaciones.

Comment: Esa es la forma de hacer una columna autoincrementable, solo quería decir que, aunque no lo he probado, en Oracle 12c ya existe la forma de declarar una columna autoincrementable.

Comment: primero agradecerte por el gran aporte, pero aun tengo una duda, el id estoy pasando como null, inserto unos 3 registros de manera normal pero ya desde el 4 registro me aparece en forma desordenada, vale decir el orden de los id, por favor si alguien podria ayudarme. se los agradece.

Comment: A que le llamas _desordenado_. Nunca he visto una secuencia asignar el 17, luego el 11 y finalmente el 14, lo que para mi sería desordenado. Estoy seguro que quieres decir otra cosa, pero no logro imaginar cuál.